# Fill Factor for Datawarehouse - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, fillfactor

I am planning to set up a script to rebuild all the indexes in one particular database. How do I set the fill factor? How do I determine the fill factor here.

My database is used for data-warehouse purpose. It is insert/update heavy system. Could some suggest me which is the good fill factor rate and how do I know if this fill factor is right.

I am using SQL Server 2008 database.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/16/sql-server-fillfactor-index-and-in-depth-look-at-effect-on-performance/

Comment: Thanks for the link.. JUst want to  the difference between fill-factor and Fragmentation ? How to set them right to get good performance

Answer (score 2):

You want a fillfactor of 0 because you are probably loading the file once every period (every night, once a week). If you are going to do massive inserts/updates and you may find that its a lot quicker to drop all the indexes, load the table and recreate all the indexes. So if you are not going to add rows as they come in you want as few reads as possible when searching for something so you want your pages to be totally full. If you are doing inserts you want empty spaces on the page to avoid page splits and that is why you would set a fill factor of not 0.

Comment: I have total of 200 (Dimensions and fact tables) Some of the fact would get a maximum of 5000 records per day. Some may get less < 1000 records per day. Updates are like < 10000 records per day. How should I set fill factor in this case?

Comment: How often per day are they being updated? Is it continuous or all at once? How large are the tables?

Comment: If its updated once a day I would leave the fill factor at 0. If there are page splits, they only happen during the insert/updates if necessary but then your selects will go faster because SQL Server will have fewer pages to hunt through. You will still have to keep an eye on how long the insert/update takes. If it starts getting very slow (on such a small volume all things being equal it should not too long) you will have to add a fill factor of nonzero and recreate/reorg the index.